# Get request doesn't work somehow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get photos from instagram by get request, 
I tried `jQuery.get()` which worked well for other purpose of get request which is not instagram,
but for this one it doesn't work.
I used postman and I get the request no problem at all, 
I also tried to change from `jQuery.get()` to `jQuery.getJSON()` and still no luck.

By the way, tried to get the request with NodeJS using `request` module and it works fine.

Hope you can help, here is my simple code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {

            $.get("https://www.instagram.com/uefachampionsleague/media/",
                function (data) {
                    alert(items[0].id);
                },"json");
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<p></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check Developer tools console for errors regarding [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), because `instagram` don't allow you to do that in a browser

Comment: you have to register you app to use instagram data,, then with your backend and valid token can access data :\

Comment: try setting dataType to jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your application and then set the credentials in the AJAX request, or you can also use the [`crossorigenme`](https://crossorigin.me/) proxy:

```js
$(function () {
  $.get('https://crossorigin.me/https://www.instagram.com/uefachampionsleague/media/', function(data) { console.log(data); }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As Jaromanda added "It's worth noting the caveat on crossorigin.me - **PLEASE DO NOT USE THE PROXY ON A PRODUCTION SITE** - if you want to "bypass" `CORS`, use your own <s>damned</s> server to do it".

Comment: It's worth noting the caveat on `crossorigin.me` - **PLEASE DO NOT USE THE PROXY ON A PRODUCTION SITE** - if you want to "bypass" CORS, **use your own damned server to do it**

Comment: Just to mention, he said nothing about a production application, anyways I'll delete the answer.

Comment: I got scared by the highlighted message, I'll update the answer then according to your comment.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding

Comment: it works, but why do I need to register my application anyway?
and why it works on nodeJS without that proxy?

Comment: Can you add your Node code as a comparison with the jQuery one?